# HAProxy: Creating an HTTP request-only log file

Tags: haproxy

I'm trying to split my HAProxy (v1.6.12) logs so that one file only contains the HTTP request logs, while the other contains only start/stop/etc logs. I have this in my config:

```
 global
   log 127.0.0.1 local2 notice
   log 127.0.0.1 local3 info info
```

As you can see, I'm trying to limit `local3` to *only* info logs, while `local2` gets logs at level notice and above.

`local2` correctly only receives logs at the notice level and above. However, `local3` is still getting all of start/stop logs, which are logged at the notice level. So this tells me that I'm maybe using the min log level stuff wrong? Or is there a bug?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to figure it out myself, but looks like the answer is by modifying the log format and rsyslog settings, because haproxy doesn't provide any "access logs" level.

Here is an example of what I did:

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1:514 len 65535 local0 info

    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

defaults
    log     global
    mode    http

frontend http-in
    bind *:443  ssl crt /usr/local/ssl/haproxy.pem
    default_backend response-ok

    option http-buffer-request
    declare capture request len 2000000000
    http-request capture req.body id 0
    log-format "[http-request]: %ci,%[capture.req.hdr(0)]"

backend response-ok
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/200.http
```

Now the next step is to change rsyslog to write all logs that starts with "[http-request]" to a different file, so I edited /etc/rsyslog.d/49-haproxy.conf like that:

```
# Collect log with UDP
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerAddress 127.0.0.1
$UDPServerRun 514

# We add :2: to remove leading whitespace
$template access_logs_form, "%msg:2:$:%\n"

# Send HAProxy access logs
:msg, contains, "[http-request]:" {
    /var/log/haproxy/haproxy-traffic.log;access_logs_form
    stop
}

# Send HAProxy messages to a dedicated logfile
:programname, startswith, "haproxy" {
    /var/log/haproxy/haproxy.log
    stop
}
```